# C# Random number not repeating

Tags: repeat

Hi I want use C# to generate random number,This is my situation.
I have a set of number 1 to 80, and wish get 5 number from the set.
If I get 1st number is 40, then I wish 2st number is 1-39 or 41-80.
If I get 2st number is 55, then I wish 3st number is 1-39 or 41-54 or 56-80
.........
.........
I do not want to compare each time (if repeat, then run random again until not repeat)
I want get a number then the int array will reduce and auto exclude the last number,
How can I run this kind of code ?
thanks

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Create a list of numbers `[1..80]`, shuffle, pick first 5.